# First resize image then save in database or save in database then resize

Tags: architecture

I would now change the first size then save 3 of image(small, medium, big) in my DB and use for show in site.
Now my question is **which's better**, First resize a image and save in 3 size or first save in db then resize in showtime?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly:

You are trying to:

```
- Save 3 images as binary type in your DB
```

or

```
- Save 1 image as binary type in your DB and
  then resize it when is requested by the 
  client application
```

If you are going to have a lot of requests, it is not a good idea to resize your images every time your client is requesting an image.

Also, depending on your application and number of images, I think it is not a good idea to store the images in the DB. You can resize and store the images on the file system and store the path of the images in the DB. You can have an asynchronous process to resize your images and your DB will be free from waiting.